# Regex to get key words, all digits and periods

Tags: python, regex

My input text looks like this:

> *Put in 3 extenders but by the 4th floor it is weak on signal these don't piggy back of each other. ST -99. 5G DL 624.26 UP 168.20 4g DL 2
>   Up .44*

I am having difficulty writing a regex that will match any instances of 4G/5G/4g/5g and give me all the corresponding measurements after the instances of these codes, which are numbers with decimals.

The output should be:

> 5G 624.26 168.20 4g 2 .44

Any thoughts how to achieve this? I am trying to do this analysis in Python.

Comment: From the expected output, it seems like you want all the words that start with a number. Is that right?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: have you tried `"[4-5][Gg]"`?  I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: When you ask a regex question, it always helps if you could supply at least a couple of passing and failing test cases. Unlike other stuff, regex really needs both the cases. More cases will get you a better matching regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the answers that say to use capture groups, but have a slightly different approach for the regex itself.  Be sure to use gi (global and case-insensitive) options to get the correct results.

```
r"([45]G).*?([\d.]+).*?([\d.]+)"
```

I'm including the link to the [online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/r/bfiJgc/1/) that I used because it explains the individual elements of the regex very well, and I've also copied in the sample python code it generated below.

```
import re

regex = r"([45]G).*?([\d.]+).*?([\d.]+)"

test_str = "Put in 3 extenders but by the 4th floor it is weak on signal these don't piggy back of each other. ST -99. 5G DL 624.26 UP 168.20 4g DL 2 Up .44"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.IGNORECASE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would separate it in different capture group like this:

`(?i)(?P<g1>5?4?G)\sDL\s(?P<g2>[^\s]*)\sUP\s(?P<g3>[^\s]*)`

`(?i)` makes the whole regex case insensitive

`(?P<g1>5?4?G)` is the first group matching on either 4g, 5g, 4G or 5G.

`(?P<g2>[^\s]*)` is the second and third group matching on everything that is not a space.

Then in Python you can do:

`match = re.match('(?i)(?P<g1>5?4?G)\sDL\s(?P<g2>[^\s]*)\sUP\s(?P<g3>[^\s]*)', input)`

And access each group like so:

`match.group('g1')` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
(5G|4G)\sDL\s(\d*[.]?\d*)\sUP\s(\d*[.]?\d*)
```

with gi flags (global, case insensitive) should work. You can modify the digit matching since I'm unsure if it's necessarily a decimal or not.

Comment: ([\d.]+) will capture an arbitrary combination of digits and decimals so may be a better option in this case

Comment: True, but at the same time it wouldn't be logical to have multiple decimal points in the same number. While _probably_ a non-factor, it's unknown what could be in the body text.

Comment: Hey, OP said all the digits and periods. That means all the digits and all the periods, right? :-)